# concatenate strings in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to concatenate strings in Node.js . I started with a very basic example, I am trying to read a file, and simply concatenate all the lines one by one to a new object, but from some reason when I do console.log, only the last line appears. Its like each new line runs over the other.

here is the code

```
fs.readFile("C:/example.srt", function(error, data) {
    if (error) { throw error; }else {
        var newData = "";
        data.toString().split("\n").forEach(function (line) {
            newData = newData + line;
        });

        console.log(newData);
    }
});
```

Comment: try fs.readFile('path_to_file', 'utf8', callback())

Comment: Can you log `data.toString().split("\n").length` at line 4?

Comment: The example is working on my side , testing on a dummy text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be running on a windows platform where the line separator is `\r\n` so when you split by `\n` the carriage return is still present which overwrites the `newData` string. Simply change to `...().split('\r\n')`

Comment: WOW you won't belive the amount of time I spent on this. Thanks!